# Editing a query with alias in firedac gives an error

Tags: delphi, alias, firedac

Run the query with a firedac query like this:

SELECT std_no, std_name as aaa, std_sex FROM student;

If you change std_sex and post

It says      invalid column name 'aaa'.

Is this really not true?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the behaviour you describe.

A work-around is as follows:

- Create persistent fields on your Student table.
- Select the `aaa` field in the Fields editor
- In its `Origin` field, enter the name of the actual table column, i.e. `std_name`.

An edit/post operation will then execute without error.  Obviously, without persistent TFields, FireDAC seems to stumble attempting to generate the SQL necessary to update the table.

Tested with Delphi Seattle.

Btw, I haven't been able to come up with a modification of your Select SQL which avoids the problem without having to use persistent TFields.

Comment: No problem with 10.3.2. Works ok without persistent fields!

Comment: It was helpful. thank you for letting me know.

So what if alias is a calculator field?

Comment: @frahaKang - what do you mean with calculator field?

Answer (score 0):

To work around the issue without using persistent TFields, you can populate the Origin property of the dataset's TFields in code at run-time. I put this statement into my dataset's AfterOpen event handler:

```
FDQuery1.FieldByName('aaa').Origin := 'std_name';
```

Regarding Branko's comment that there is no problem in 10.3.2 without persistent TFields: Actually there is no problem if UpdateMode is upWhereKeyOnly, or it's upWhereChanged and the aliased field is changing. It doesn't matter whether TFields are persistent or not. To see the problem you must have UpdateMode set to upWhereAll as this affects whether the field is included in the update statement's WHERE clause, which is where the problem is arising.